# Re factoring with Factory design patern

Tags: design-patterns

Well i am having some trouble with re-factoring old code, its a school assignment so...
I am planing to use Factory design pattern or Strategy , anyway i am not sure how to use them in this particular scenario :

```
public void sunk(int i, int j)
{
    if(map[i][j]==hit)
    {

    //if the hit is not on an edge
    if(i<9 && i>0 && j<9 && j>0)
    {

        //dec above if odd
        if(map[i-1][j]!= hit && map[i-1][j]%2==1)
        {
            //if(map[i-1][j]==13)
            map[i-1][j]= map[i-1][j] -9;
        }

        //dec above if even
        if(map[i-1][j]!= hit && map[i-1][j]%2==0)
        {
            map[i-1][j]= map[i-1][j] -2;
        }

        //dec below if odd
        if(map[i+1][j]!= hit && map[i+1][j]%2==1)
        {
            map[i+1][j]= map[i+1][j] -9;
        }

        //dec below if even
        if(map[i+1][j]!= hit && map[i+1][j]%2==0)
        {
            map[i+1][j]= map[i+1][j] -2;
        }

        //dec left if even
        if(map[i][j-1]!= hit && map[i][j-1]%2==0)
        {
            map[i][j-1]= map[i][j-1] -4;
        }

        //dec left if odd
        if(map[i][j-1]!= hit && map[i][j-1]%2==1)
        {
            map[i][j-1]= map[i][j-1] -9;
        }

        //dec right if even
        if(map[i][j+1]!= hit && map[i][j+1]%2==0)
        {
            map[i][j+1]= map[i][j+1] -4;
        }

        //dec right if odd
        if(map[i][j+1]!= hit && map[i][j+1]%2==1)
        {
            map[i][j+1]= map[i][j+1] -9;
        }
    }
```

and i goes on and on , so because i have SO MANY if-else statements i am thinking of using the above patterns.
Help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure either pattern helps you here.

`Factory` would be used to instantiate different subclasses of objects (or sets of subclasses) based on the input parameters.

`Strategy` would be used to substitute behaviour within a class at *runtime*.

Without knowing more about what the code above is trying to achieve, it's difficult to make a suggestion. For code like the above, it's possible to encapsulate into lookup tables, which will give you a concise implementation at the (enormous?) expense of readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a strategy there. First, start with a interface for the strategy. I don't know which language are you using so I'll use a java-like language.

```
interface HitStrategy {
    bool AppliesTo(map, i, j);
    void Apply(map,i,j);
}
```

Each class will implement the different if blocks:

```
class DecRightIfOdd implements HitStrategy { 
    public bool AppliesTo(map, i, j){
        return map[i][j+1]!= hit && map[i][j+1]%2==1;
    }

    public void Apply(map,i,j){
         map[i][j+1]= map[i][j+1] -9;
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can have a list of HitStrategy and find the ones that applies to the map and position, and then call the Apply method.

So, why is that better that having a bunch of ifs? you can use inheritance. In your example, you have two Dec Right, one for Odd and one for even. You can do this:

```
abstract class DecRight implements HitStrategy { 
    public bool AppliesTo(map, i, j){
        return map[i][j+1]!= hit;
    }
    public abstract Apply(map,i,j);
}

class DecRightIfOdd inherits DecRight { 
    public bool AppliesTo(map, i, j){
        return base(map,i,j) && map[i][j+1]%2==0;
    }

    public void Apply(map,i,j){
         map[i][j+1]= map[i][j+1] -4;
    }
}

class DecRightIfEven inherits DecRight { 
    public bool AppliesTo(map, i, j){
        return base(map,i,j) && map[i][j+1]%2==1;
    }

    public void Apply(map,i,j){
         map[i][j+1]= map[i][j+1] -9;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.